# How to get Values of Group of textbox and put them in a ( key : Value ) array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

How to get values of group of textbox and put them in a `(key : value)` array using JQuery?

```
foreach ($students as $value) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="result[]" class="result" id="<?= $value['stuId'];?>" type="text" required=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I don't know how to get values of a group of input values.

Which technique is useful in that case and how can I make the keys of the array is the input id?

Comment: Do you want array, or object? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144705/best-way-to-store-a-key-value-array-in-javascript

Comment: Well .. 
My Intention was to send that array through 
$.post("URL",{array : myArray},function(data){//code});
and manipulate that array in the URL located function.

What is better an object or an array ?

Comment: Both will work...you can use json format, if you wish...

Comment: oh ya I'd like to learn that  .. can you recommend me a link to learn this technique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uyko2ahx/

Depending on your needs, you can use simple array, or object, with key:value pair:

```
arr=[];
$( ".result" ).each(function( index ) {
 key=$( this ).prop('id');
 value=$(this).val();
    arr.push(key+':'+value);   
});

console.log(arr);

obj={};

$( ".result" ).each(function( index ) {
 key=$( this ).prop('id');
 value=$(this).val();

    obj[key]=value; 
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I'd never do it better than yours .. Thank you