# Promise.map over object

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I've an object like;

```
{ '6': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '7': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '8': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '9': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '10': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '11': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } } }
```

I want to iterate over it like;

```
return Promise.map(myObj, function(minute, minuteIndex) {
```

so basically minute should hold the data and minuteIndex should be holding the index.

I can do it with lodash but bluebird can't somehow.

```
_.forEach(hour.minutes, function(minute, minuteIndex) {
```

I know that this code was working before but now can't get it so.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is that an object with numbers for keys? Maybe you should use an array instead?

Comment: I can't. This is a special structure to hold per-minute stastistics of data over mongoose. I need those indexes.

Comment: I don't understand. An array has numbers as keys. You want numbers as keys. Logical conclusion: Use an array.

Comment: Nah that could be only a javascript object; http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144737/170181 - which is already what I'm using as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map the object's keys into an array and give that to `Promise.map()`:

```
function process(stats) {
    var statsArray = Object.keys(stats).map(key => ({
        minute: key, minuteIndex: stats[key]
    }));
    return Promise.map(statsArray, item => {
        // work with item.minute & item.minuteIndex
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var twitchStats = {
  '6': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '7': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '8': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '9': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '10': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } },
  '11': { stream: { twitch: [Object] } }
};

process(twitchStats).then(result => {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Promise.all(

  Object.keys(twitchStats).map(key => Promise.resolve({
        minute: key, minuteIndex: twitchStats[key]
    })

)
```

Use combination of `Promise.all()` with `map()` functions. Be careful: `map()` has to **return promise** in order for `Promise.all()` work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the object to an array, using _.toPairs, then you should be able to use the Promise.map methods.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify in your question if you are using the `Promise.map()` callback to return a promise or a value. If you only want to return a value, there is not much benefit to using `Promise.map()` over `forEach`.

Bluebird's `Promise.map()` used for it's most basic interface is according to the docs:

> to replace the .push+Promise.all boilerplate

Assuming you want to return promises, you can use `lodash.map()` to iterate over the object and have the key available when *creating* the promise, then use `Promise.all()` to execute them.

```
  let jobs =
    _.map(myObj, (minute, minuteIndex) => {
      return fnThatReturnsPromise(minute, minuteIndex);
    });

  return Promise.all(jobs);
```

Or as a single statement that more closely resembles your desired format

```
  return Promise.all(_.map(myObj, (minute, minuteIndex) => {
    return fnThatReturnsPromise(minute, minuteIndex);
  }));
```