# Pushing to an array inside an object

Tags: javascript

I just recently picked up JS and have been working on an exercise to sort people from an array of records, `ancestry`, into the centuries they lived in and their ages. Here's a sample element from `ancestry`:

```
{
name:   "Carolus Haverbeke"
sex:    "m"
born:   1832
died:   1905
father: "Carel Haverbeke"
mother: "Maria van Brussel"
}
```

Here's my attempt:

```
ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
  var ages = {};
  var century = Math.ceil(person.died / 100);

  if (century in ages) 
    ages[century].push(person.died - person.born);
  else
    ages[century] = person.died - person.born;
});
```

This is the general format I'm trying to store in `ages`, which maps each century to an array of the people's ages:

```
{
16: [24, 51, 16]
17: [73, 22]
18: [54, 65, 28]
}
```

I'm really confused as this code only saves the first person in `ancestry` into `ages`. I thought it might be because I defined `ages` inside the `forEach`, but when I move `var ages = {}` outside I get this:

`TypeError: ages[century].push is not a function (line 18)`

Could someone please help explain what's going on and the code should be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr

```
var ancestry = [{ ... }, { ... }, ...],
    ages = {};

ancestry.forEach(function (person) {
    var century = Math.ceil(person.died / 100),
        age = person.died - person.born;

    !ages[century] && (ages[century] = []);

    ages[century].push(age);
});

console.log(ages);
```

---

We will discribe your code to understand problems:

Assume we have an `ancestry` Array (that means `var ancestry = [{...}, {...}, ...]` is in this form and each item look like this:

```
var ancestry = [{
    name: "Carolus Haverbeke",
    sex:  "m",
    born: 1832,
    died: 1905,
    father: "Carel Haverbeke",
    mother: "Maria van Brussel"
}, {
    name: "Carolus Haverbeke",
    sex:  "m",
    born: 1722,
    died: 1805,
    father: "Carel Haverbeke",
    mother: "Maria van Brussel"
}, {
    name: "Carolus Haverbeke",
    sex:  "m",
    born: 1666,
    died: 1705,
    father: "Carel Haverbeke",
    mother: "Maria van Brussel"
}, {
    name: "Carolus Haverbeke",
    sex:  "m",
    born: 1622,
    died: 1715,
    father: "Carel Haverbeke",
    mother: "Maria van Brussel"
}];
```

with different data.

To achieve what you want, follow this steps:

```
// Create your variable in the parent scope to allow variables to exist after the end of `forEach` method.
var ages = {};

// In the ancestry Array, we will loop on all items like `{ ... }`.
ancestry.forEach(function (person) {
  // For each loop `person` will contain the current `{ ... }` item.

  // Because we want add this property to the existant object, we don't need a new object. And as you said,
  // 1. `ages` will be deleted in each loop because is defined into `forEach`
  // var ages = {};

      // We get the century of die.
  var century = Math.ceil(person.died / 100),
      // and age of die
      age = person.died - person.born;

  // now if the century property not exist, create a new array into to accept all centuries after.
  if (!ages[century]) {
      ages[century] = [];
  }
  // equivalent to `!ages[century] && (ages[century] = []);`

    // in all cases, just push the value to the end.
    ages[century].push(age);
});

// Still exist !
console.log(ages); // Object {18: Array(2), 19: Array(1), 20: Array(1)}
```

your final format is what you want:

```
{
    18: [39, 93],
    19: [83],
    20: [73]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to create array in else statement like this `ages[century] = [person.died - person.born];`

```
    ancestry.forEach(function(person) {
      var ages = {};
      var century = Math.ceil(person.died / 100);

      if (century in ages) 
        {
        ages[century].push(person.died - person.born);
            }
      else
           {       
        ages[century] = [person.died - person.born];
           }
    });
```

Comment: I'm trying to save an array of ages - your code means that age gets overwritten every time the century occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `ages` array outside.

The error you are getting because you have not initialised your `ages[century]` as an `array`. Hence it will just store one value.

add this line

```
ages[century] = []
```

`ages[century].push()` will work fine then

Here is the change you need to do in your `if-else`

```
if (ages[century]){
   ages[century].push(person.died - person.born);
}
else{
   ages[century] = []
   ages[century].push(person.died - person.born);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the `century` variables as keys in a key-value pair (a type of array called an "associative array") and then store `ages` into another array within that array (remember `century` is your key and the value is an array).

**Basically, it's a 2-dimensional associative array so you might as well just use an object.**

So it needs to look like `var ages = {16: {24, 51, 16}, 17: {73, 22}, 18: {54, 65, 28}};`

or

`var ages = {16: {}, 17: {}, 18: {}};`
and then you can recursively push those values onto the appropriate key's array.

Key-Value Pairs: [Best way to store a key=>value array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144705/best-way-to-store-a-key-value-array-in-javascript)

Multidimensional Associative Arrays (objects): [Multi-dimensional associative arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329092/multi-dimensional-associative-arrays-in-javascript)

W3School (JavaScript Objects): https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

You could just store the array of ages in an object and access that array by the key (which in your case you have declared to be `century`).

If it were me, I would make `person` an object and then store each person's `birthday`, `date-of-death`, and `age-at-death` as an attribute in a database.

Out of curiosity, what do you do when someone lives in two different centuries? I was born in 1987 and it's 2017 so did I live in the 20th or the 21st century?