# Storing key value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we store key value pair in javascript in this way?
array variable arr;

```
arr[key1]={value11,value12,value13...}
arr[key2]={value21,value22,value33...}
```

example:

```
arr["class"]={8,9,10}
arr["section"]={a,b,c}
```

and so on...

I am new to javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to store a key=>value array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144705/best-way-to-store-a-key-value-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a series or ordered list of values that you're going to index numerically, you'd typically use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). So for instance, `[8, 9, 10]` is an array with three entries (the numbers `8`, `9`, and `10`).

To store a keyed set of values, you'd usually use an object (if the set of key/value pairs is reasonably consistent and the keys are strings¹) or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (if the set of key/value pairs varies over time, or keys are not strings).

Example of an object with an array of numbers:

```
const obj = {
    class: [8, 9, 10]
};
```

or building it up:

```
const obj = {};
obj.class = [8, 9, 10];
// or
// obj["class"] = [8, 9, 10];
```

In this case, the key/value pairs are called **properties** of the object.

Or with a `Map`:

```
const map = new Map();
map.set("class", [8, 9, 10]);
```

In this case, the key/value pairs are called **entries** of the map.

---

¹ Technically objects can also have properties keyed by Symbols, but that's not usually something you have to deal with when first getting started.