# How to dynamically create nested object in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an object that looks like this:

```
{
   Player1: [
      {cardName: "test", 
       balanceNum: null,  
       ability:""}
   ],
   Player2: [
      {cardName: "test", 
       balanceNum: null,  
       ability:""}
   ],
   .
   .
   .
}
```

At the moment I am currently using this attempt to loop through and create this dynamically. Player gets update through the loop and I want each new entry to start with player1 and continue to playerN.

```
var playersInfoList = [];
var playerStatus = [];
var player = "";
var index = 1;
for (i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
   player = "player" + index++;
   playerStatus.push({
      cardName: "", 
      balanceNum: null,  
      ability:""
   });
   playersInfoList.push({
      [player]: playerStatus
   });
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the second array.

---

Also, key-value array's are somehow different in JS. Please check [Best way to store a key=>value array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144705/best-way-to-store-a-key-value-array-in-javascript/1144737).

---

This should get you the desired output;

```js
const playerCount = 15;   // example
var playersInfoList = {}; // Result

for (i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {

   // Create key as 'player' + i
   var key = "player" + i;
   
   // Add new object
   playersInfoList[key] = {
      cardName: "", 
      balanceNum: null,  
      ability:""
   };
}
console.log(playersInfoList); // Show result
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I needed! I just added a + 1 to the i in the var key so that is starts with player1 instead of player0

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
playerCount = 5;
const result = Array.from(Array(playerCount)).reduce( (current, _, i) => {
  current[`player${i+1}`] =  [{
    cardName: "", 
    balanceNum: null,  
    ability:""
  }];
  return current;
}, {} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me get this straight: you want that your array contains several attributes having key = playerN and value the struct of a player. Right?

If so, you don't want playerStatus to a list but an object (you can stille iterate it's attributes as you do with an array). So your code turns like this:

```
const playerStatus = [];
var player = "";
// as said in the comments below there is no need to use the variale index as i is already incrementing and keeping track of index

 for (i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
    player = "player" + i;
    playerStatus[player] =
    {
       cardName: "", 
       balanceNum: null,  
       ability:""
    };
    
    // Also i don't see the utility of the other array
 }
```

Alternatively i suggest you to use a map with key = playerN and value = ObjectPlayer, it's pretty the same but you can use some useful buil-in functions.

Comment: Why would you keep track on the `index` while the `for()` already provides one?

Comment: I just copy and pasted his code, don't ask me questions

Comment: So you're giving 'bad' advice because OP showed you that? Doesn't make any sense....

Comment: I told him how to achieve his goal, but i guess you're right i'm doing a clean up

Comment: Anyway by "copy and paste" his code i mean i copied and pasted the code that was on the answer changing the part he wanted to be changed, that's not a bad advice, look closer at the question :)