# Filter an array of objects with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, selector

[image: Filtering an array of key'd objects]

How do you filter an array of key: objects where the value you filter by is in the object?

Comment: Please provide more information: the array of objects (in code, not just a link), the nested value you want to filter by, and how you want to filter it (eg alphabetically, smallest number to largest, etc).

Comment: `[ keyMe:object1,  keyYou:Object3]`  if your array has "literal" key:value elements then  this:   `KeyedArray["keyMe"]`  is all you need.  You can use a variable too.  [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144705/463206) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
array.filter((item)=>{return item.someKey==='valueYouWant'})
```

in your example you can do something like this:

```
const filtered=array.filter((item)=>{return item.categoryId<22})
```