# print Associative array elements one by one using javascript only

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slideStart = 1;
var slideCount = 4;
function callArr() {
    var arrName = {"rose":"5", "daisy":"4",
                   "orchid":"3", "sunFlower":"10",
                   "Lily":"15"};
    for (var flwr in arrName) {
        if (slideStart <= slideCount) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += flwr +
                                                         "   >>>>>>>>   " +
                                                         arrName[flwr] +
                                                         "<br />";
            slideStart++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to access array elements individually on any event. can any please help me out on this????

Comment: You have the code to print the array. Now, what do you want to know?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on any event"?

Comment: Just FYI, javascript doesn't have associative arrays.  What you're working with there is actually an object.  Treating them as associative arrays can have unintended consequences. http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful

Comment: this code print only first element... i want all elements to print one by one when i click on a link.. Is it possible??

Comment: Maybe you should remove the if from your code? And especially, don't use `>` in HTML, unless you mean to use a tag.

Comment: This is not an Array, is a JS Object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will print only the first element since you use condition like this

```
if (slideStart <= slideCount)
```

Modify your code to iterate through the object properties. One of the possible solutions:

```
var slideStart = 0;
var slideCount = 4;
function callArr() {
    var arrName = {"rose":"5", "daisy":"4",
                   "orchid":"3", "sunFlower":"10",
                   "Lily":"15"};
    var i = 0;
    for (var flwr in arrName) {
        if (i == slideStart) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += flwr +
                                                         "    " +
                                                         arrName[flwr] +
                                                         "<br />";
            slideStart++;
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2nDv8/

As you can see, it prints the next property after every call.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to access anywere, you could declare it as globla var:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slideStart = 1;
var slideCount = 4;
var arrName = {"rose":"5", "daisy":"4",
                   "orchid":"3", "sunFlower":"10",
                   "Lily":"15"}; //Declare var outside, so it's global
function callArr() {    
    for (var flwr in arrName) {
        if (slideStart <= slideCount) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += flwr +
                                                         "   >>>>>>>>   " +
                                                         arrName[flwr] +
                                                         "<br />";
            slideStart++;
            //break; //This prevents from showing more. Erase it
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Also note that the `break` statement was causing to show only the first element

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly cross-browser compatible, but you can use `Object.keys(arrName)`. Or actually create and store an array that acts the same, if you're actually concerned about cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It only prints once because you put a `"break"` inside your loop. This code will print all elements without problems. One problem is also caused by your `slideStart` and `slideCount` variables. If you want to print all of them, change `slideStart` to 0 so that it will print all the elements, not just 4 of those..Hope that helps:

```
function callArr() {
    var arrName = {"rose":"5", "daisy":"4",
                   "orchid":"3", "sunFlower":"10",
                   "Lily":"15"};
    for (var flwr in arrName) {
        if (slideStart <= slideCount) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += flwr +
                                                         "   >>>>>>>>   " +
                                                         arrName[flwr] +
                                                         "<br />";
            slideStart++;
            //break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you want. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hsn4c/1/

```
function callArr() {
    var slideStart = 0;
    var slideCount = 4;

    var arrName = {
        "rose": "5",
        "daisy": "4",
        "orchid": "3",
        "sunFlower": "10",
        "Lily": "15"
    };
    for (var flwr in arrName) {
        if (slideStart <= slideCount) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += flwr + ">>>>>" + arrName[flwr] + "<br />";
            slideStart++;
            //break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '==========<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4 the reply.... It is now printing all values at once... i want that when i click on a link, first element is printed. then on second click, second element and so on....