# If Array keys are actually strings, then what differentiates an Array from an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I mean, apart from the [].prototype methods and the strictly-"stringmeric" keys?

Anything?

Could an array said to be an object that by convention has exclusively "numeric" string values as keys, and inherits methods from Array.prototype?

Are there any other differences?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object) helps.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference is the automatic behavior of the `.length` property.

[Here is a slightly old but still interesting article on the topic.](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

Answer (score 1):

You get the Array prototype such as

```
$ ['foo', 'bar'].length
2

$ ['foo', 'bar'].join('|')
'foo|bar'

// etc...
```

Read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype