# Javascript: how to set a variable's value as the key in an associative array?

Tags: javascript

I need to build a dynamic associative in the following way:

I have a variable named param

```
var arr = { param's value : "another value"};
```

I am unable to put param's value as the key.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
var arr = {};
arr[ param + "'s value"] = "another value";
```

Note: 'var arr = {}', here arr is Object instead of array. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object)

Comment: Haha what kind of weird key can have this name :D ?

Comment: I think ***'s value*** was OPs attempt to explain the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's unclear what you're asking, but taking a stab at it: If you mean you have a variable, `param`, and want to use its value (just its value) as a property name:

```
var obj = {}; // Note "obj", not "arr" -- it's not an array
obj[param] = "another value";
```

That works because in JavaScript you can access the property of an object using both "dot" notation and a literal (`obj.foo`), or bracketed notation and a string (`obj["foo"]`). In the second case, the string can be result of any expression, and the constraints on property names that apply to literals don't apply (because we're not using a literal).

Comment: "I have a variable named param" I think the OP just wants the value of param. BTW, seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I think your solution is the same as Anoop's, correct?

Comment: @curious1: Actually I think we both slightly misunderstood. Thanks to OneKitten, I've updated to what I think you want.

Comment: thanks a millions for your follow-up!

Answer (score 3):

Just put the key in quotes:

```
var arr = { "param's value" : "another value"};
```

Comment: I think he might have meant a variable instead of a string.

Comment: Oh.. so I guess I missunderstood the question. Thanks.

Comment: +1 in case `param` isn't a variable, though.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to use the value stored in the variable `param` as a key ?

If so:

```
var param = 'something',
    myObject = {};

myObject[param] = 'something else';
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's an object `{}` an array is written with (square)brackets `[]`.

Setting a new prop or editing one on an object can be done so:

```
var obj = {};
obj.key = 'value';
// or 
obj['key'] = 'value';

//object inside an object. 
var obj = {};
obj.objNested = {
    key: 'value'
}; 
// or
obj.objNested = {};
obj.objNested.key = 'value';

// or with a variable;
var obj = {};
var key = 'prop';
obj[key] = 'value';

// an array containing objects:
var array = [
     { key: value },
     { key: value }
];
```