# Accessing Multidimensional Arrays JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array of people and I need to access individual values within the array such as first name.

The array is as follows:

```
$people = array(
'jjones' => array('firstName' => 'Jim', 'lastName' => 'Jones', 'age' => 20, 'major' => 'Computer Science', 'phone' => '212-460-9393', 'email' => 'jjones@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'OH'),
'asmith' => array('firstName' => 'April', 'lastName' => 'Smith', 'age' => 19, 'major' => 'Mechanical Engineering', 'phone' => '913-939-3929', 'email' => 'asmith@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'WY'),
'pstemple' => array('firstName' => 'Pat', 'lastName' => 'Stemple', 'age' => 21, 'major' => 'Theater Performance', 'phone' => '917-222-2232', 'email' => 'pstemple@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'NY'),
'jjones1' => array('firstName' => 'Janet', 'lastName' => 'Jones', 'age' => 22, 'major' => 'Botany', 'phone' => '817-332-9392', 'email' => 'jjones1@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'CA'),
'llerner' => array('firstName' => 'Leon', 'lastName' => 'Lerner', 'age' => 18, 'major' => 'Biology', 'phone' => '315-444-3494', 'email' => 'llerner@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'OH'),
'mmeyer' => array('firstName' => 'Margret', 'lastName' => 'Meyer', 'age' => 24, 'major' => 'Interactive Media Studies', 'phone' => '219-333-0303', 'email' => 'mmeyer@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'OH'),
'achaudhry' => array('firstName' => 'Anik', 'lastName' => 'Chaudhry', 'age' => 19, 'major' => 'Management Information Systems', 'phone' => '914-555-5555', 'email' => 'achaudhry@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'NY'),
'sdogg' => array('firstName' => 'Snoop', 'lastName' => 'Dogg', 'age' => 42, 'major' => 'Botany', 'phone' => '414-333-2433', 'email' => 'sdogg@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'CA'),
'bclinton' => array('firstName' => 'Bill', 'lastName' => 'Clinton', 'age' => 25, 'major' => 'Political Science', 'phone' => '933-440-3033', 'email' => 'bclinton@miamioh.edu', 'state' => 'AK'),);
```

I have set up my system so it will accept a partial query. Ie. If I want the count of how many IDs contain JJ I will get two. When I set up my javascript however, I cannot seem to access the information about each of the IDs. For example when using JJ:

```
        console.log(count);
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json[0]);
        console.log(json[0].firstName);
```

Will return the following in the console window:
[image: Console Image]
However I can drill down into the console.log(json);
[image: Drilldown]

I need a way to display directly display a value like the first name of JJONES in the console.

Comment: Image URLs because they show up small: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QdEn3.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/QwnwO.png

Comment: try `json.jjones.firstName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHP associative array, when JSON encoded is transformed into an object, not an array. So you can't use `[0]` to access the first. To access the `jjones` object, you can do:

```
console.log( json.jjones.firstName );
console.log( json['jjones'].firstName );
```

To iterate over them you can do:

```
for(var key in json){
    // key is jjones, asmith etc
    console.log( json[key].firstName );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `json[0].jjones.firstName`, in console You can see that your `json[0]` is object with property `jjones` and ther is no property `firstName`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and PHP have very different ideas of an array.

PHP allows both traditional `numeric` arrays as well as associative arrays.

JavaScript has `numeric` arrays and it uses `objects` as associative arrays.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object) goes into detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
   console.log(json[0]['jjones'].firstName);
```

or

```
   console.log(json[0].jjones.firstName);
```