# What is difference of "Array" & "Object" in JS

Tags: javascript

What is difference of "Array" & "Object" in JS.
I know only that:

```
var variable=[1, 2, 3, "Array"]
var varibale1={Fist:1, Second:"Some String", Third:"Object"}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you compare "Array" with "Object", you should see the following
>   similarities and differences:
>
> - "Array" is subclass, or sub-prototype, of "Object". So "Array"    inherits all features from "Object".
> - "Array" is not a new data type. "Array" and "Object" are sharing the    same data type "object".
> - The "typeof" operator on an "Array" object returns "object".
> - The "instanceof" operator on an "Array" object matches "Array". It    also matches "Object", because "Array" is a subclass of "Object".
> - An object of "Object" can have indexed properties using the same    syntax as "Array" objects.
> - An object of "Object" is not an object of "Array".
> - An object of "Array" is also an object of "Object".

Source: http://www.herongyang.com/JavaScript/Object-Compare-Array-Object-Difference.html

Answer (score 0):

For beginners, it is just two different ways of organizing data. Arrays are ordered lists, whereas objects contain key-value pairs. This difference is important because when you want to access or set the data, for arrays you use indices like `variable[0]` to get the first item. For objects, however, you would have to do `variable1["First"]` or `variable1.First`