# What’s the difference between “{}” and “[]” while declaring a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, declaration

What’s the difference between “{}” and “[]” while declaring a JavaScript array?
Normally I declare like

```
var a=[];
```

What is the meaning of declaring the array as `var a={}`

Comment: `var a = {};` is an object-_key-value_ pairs. `var a = [];` is an array-values stored in sequential indexes.

Comment: You are not creating array when you are using `{}`, you are creating `object`

Comment: What is the exact question? Difference between _object_ and _array_? What are you trying to do? Add some more code

Comment: I wants to know the difference between [] and {} declaration,
I got your answer  @Tushar

Comment: This may be a Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object

Comment: But My question is syntax wise doubt, Not asking the same Initially @jfriend00

Comment: The answer is that `[]` and `{}` are declaring different things as described in the dup..  `{}` is NOT an array.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Nobody seems to be explaining the difference between an array and an object.

`[]` is declaring an array.

`{}` is declaring an object.

An array has all the features of an object with additional features (you can think of an array like a sub-class of an object) where additional methods and capabilities are added in the Array sub-class.  In fact, `typeof [] === "object"` to further show you that an array is an object.

The additional features consist of a magic `.length` property that keeps track of the number of items in the array and a whole slew of methods for operating on the array such as `.push()`, `.pop()`, `.slice()`, `.splice()`, etc...  You can see a list of array methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

An object gives you the ability to associate a property name with a value as in:

```
var x = {};
x.foo = 3;
x["whatever"] = 10;
console.log(x.foo);      // shows 3
console.log(x.whatever); // shows 10
```

Object properties can be accessed either via the `x.foo` syntax or via the array-like syntax `x["foo"]`.  The advantage of the latter syntax is that you can use a variable as the property name like `x[myvar]` and using the latter syntax, you can use property names that contain characters that Javascript won't allow in the `x.foo` syntax.

A property name can be any string value.

---

An array is an object so it has all the same capabilities of an object plus a bunch of additional features for managing an **ordered**, **sequential** list of numbered indexes starting from `0` and going up to some length.  Arrays are typically used for an ordered list of items that are accessed by numerical index.  And, because the array is ordered, there are lots of useful features to manage the order of the list `.sort()` or to add or remove things from the list.

Comment: Why do I can do `[].` but not `{}.`?

Comment: @SurajJain - I don't understand the context of that.  Perhaps you should write your own question and explain the overall context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually we are able to do anything that we can do with array using empty array literal like `[].splice` so on, but using empty object literal `{}` we are not, like if I do `{}.hasOwnProperty` it errors out, why so?

Comment: @SurajJain - It probably has to do with the language grammar in context because `{}` also signifies a new block so you can't use it to denote an object in a context where it could mean a new block or where its meaning could be ambiguous.  You can do `let val = {value: true}.hasOwnProperty("value");
console.log(val);`.

Comment: Yeah, might be that, it also signifies a new block. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You can do  `({}).hasOwnProperty()` @SurajJain

Answer (score 18):

When you declare

```
var a=[];
```

you are declaring a empty array.

But when you are declaring

```
var a={};
```

you are declaring a Object .

Although Array is also Object in Javascript but it is numeric key paired values.
Which have all the functionality of object but Added some few method of Array like Push,Splice,Length and so on.

So if you want Some values where you need to use numeric keys use Array.
else use object. 
you can Create object like:

```
var a={name:"abc",age:"14"};
```

And can access values like

```
console.log(a.name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mytri

Comment: How to create instances and access the Key-Value Pair

Comment: A Small example code will be very Useful for me @Tushar

Comment: Example is useful @Mytri

Comment: @Venkat `var arr = ['A', 'B']; console.log(arr[0]) // A` and `var obj = { name: 'A', surname: 'B'}; console.log(obj.name); // A OR console.log(obj['name'])`

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = [];
```

it is use for brackets for an array of simple values.
eg.

```
var name=["a","b","c"]

var a={}
```

is use for value arrays and objects/properties also.
eg.

```
var programmer = { 'name':'special', 'url':'www.google.com'}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be understood like this:

```
var a= []; //creates a new empty array
var a= {}; //creates a new empty object
```

You can also understand that

`var a = {};` is equivalent to `var a= new Object();`

**Note:**

You can use Arrays when you are bothered about the order of elements(*of same type*) in your collection else you can use objects. In objects the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: So what is the difference between an array and an object?

Comment: @nnnnnn:- This can be referred: [What is the difference between an array and an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object)

Comment: @RahulTripathi nnnnnn means you should also explain the difference between them and when should use array vs object

Comment: @nnnnnn, Tushar That would be noise anyways, it wasn't the question, nor should it be. It's a separate answer that should be in a separate question.

Comment: When order of the elements in the collection is required then you can use Arrays, when order is not important then we can use objects.

Comment: @RahulTripathi - It's not just when you have order or not.  Arrays are more like a sequence of elements where you may want to know how many you have in the collection and you may want to manage items in the collection (search for them, remove some, add some, move some around).  There are plenty of times to use an array when order is not the main reason to use an array or even when order is not important at all.

Answer (score 1):

they are two different things..

`[]` is declaring an Array:
given, a list of elements held by numeric index.

`{}` is declaring a new object:
given, an object with fields with Names and type+value,
some like to think of it as "Associative Array".
but are not arrays, in their representation.

You can read more @ [This Article](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of JSON

object = {} | { members }

- members = pair | pair, members
- pair = string : value

array = [] | [ elements ]

- elements = value | value elements

value =
string|number|object|array|true|false|null

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript Arrays and Objects are actually very similar, although on the outside they can look a bit different.

For an array:

```
var array = [];
array[0] = "hello";
array[1] = 5498;
array[536] = new Date();
```

As you can see arrays in JavaScript can be sparse (valid indicies don't have to be consecutive) and they can contain **any** type of variable! That's pretty convenient.

But as we all know JavaScript is strange, so here are some weird bits:

```
array["0"] === "hello"; // This is true
array["hi"]; // undefined
array["hi"] = "weird"; // works but does not save any data to array
array["hi"]; // still undefined!
```

This is because everything in JavaScript is an Object (which is why you can also create an array using `new Array()`). As a result every index in an array is turned into a string and then stored in an object, so an array is just an object that doesn't allow anyone to store anything with a key that isn't a positive integer.

So what are Objects?

Objects in JavaScript are just like arrays but the "index" can be any string.

```
var object = {};
object[0] = "hello"; // OK
object["hi"] = "not weird"; // OK
```

You can even opt to not use the square brackets when working with objects!

```
console.log(object.hi); // Prints 'not weird'
object.hi = "overwriting 'not weird'";
```

You can go even further and define objects like so:

```
var newObject = {
    a: 2,
};
newObject.a === 2; // true
```

Comment: But in the latest chrome and firefox versions ```array["hi"] = "weird"; array["hi"];// gives output as weird```

Answer (score 0):

`[ ]` - this is used whenever we are declaring an empty array,

`{ }` - this is used whenever we declare an empty object

```js
typeof([ ]) //object
```

```js
typeof({ }) //object
```

but if your run

```js
[ ].constructor.name  //Array
```

so from this, you will understand it is an array here Array is the name of the base class.
The JavaScript Array class is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays which are high-level, list-like objects.