# How to push all objects into another array using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have 2 arrays,

```
$scope.first = [
  { fName:'Alex', lName='Doe' },
  { fName:'John', lName='S' }
]

var second= [
  { fName:'Tom', lName='M', email:'tom@gmail.com' },
  { fName:'Jerry', lName='L', email:'jerry@gmail.com' }
]
```

I need to push second array into first array and want to result like:

```
$scope.first = [
  { fName:'Alex', lName='Doe' },
  { fName:'John', lName='S' },
  { fName:'Tom', lName='M', email:'tom@gmail.com' },
  { fName:'Jerry', lName='L', email:'jerry@gmail.com' }
]
```

Comment: with concat...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to push elements from one array into an existing array you can do

```
[].push.apply($scope.first, second);
```

If you want to create a new array that contains elements of both arrays, use concat:

```
$scope.first = $scope.first.concat(second);
```

Comment: `[].push.apply()` what you mean by `[ ]`, first array(`$scope.first`)?

Comment: `[]` is an array :) You could also write `Array.prototype.push.apply(...)` or `$scope.first.push.apply(...)` or `second.push.apply(...)`. It doesn't matter. It#s just a way to reference the push method.

Comment: `[]` in js represents an array. Read more here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514915/what-s-the-difference-between-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

I would try 
    $scope.first.concat($scope.second)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.first = [
  { fName:'Alex', lName='Doe' },
  { fName:'John', lName='S' }
]

var second= [
  { fName:'Tom', lName='M', email:'tom@gmail.com' },
  { fName:'Jerry', lName='L', email:'jerry@gmail.com' }
]

$scope.first = $scope.first.concat(second)
```