# JavaScript: in what sense are objects `{}` and arrays `[]` the same or different

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to understand the following output:

```
'use strict';
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf([]));
// [] 
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype));
// {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf([]) == Array.prototype);
// true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Array.prototype);
// true
console.log([]=={});
// false
console.log([]==={});
// false
```

In particular, why are lines 6 and 8 evaluated to be `true`, whereas lines 10 and 12 are evaluated to be `false`.#

**Edit: I made a stupid typo on lines 6 and 8, which I have now edited. This makes the question different. Apologies.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the difference between “{}” and “\[\]” while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514915/what-s-the-difference-between-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Here are 2 algorithms used for `==` and `===` comparisons: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6. It may help understand differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All prototypes in Javascript eventually inherit from the same object prototype. That's why if you will add a property to the object prototype, all the objects in your program will end up having this property.
In lines 6 and 8 you are comparing 
Object.prototype to itself, which is equal.

However in lines 10 and 12, you are comparing 2 different objects, they may share the same prototype, but these are completely two different objects in memory.

Answer (score 2):

In lines 6 and 8, you are literally comparing two exact same expressions.

`(X)===(X)` is always<sup>1</sup> true for any X, and in that case `(X)==(X)` is also automatically true (not always the other way round).

`[]` and `{}` are not the same, hence the `false` from line 10 and 12.

<sup>(1) assuming of course that `X` is a non-destructive or read-only expression, if `X` is something like `(Y++)` then this doesn't hold.</sup>

Comment: Also `{} === {}` or `[] === []` are both false so it's not as easy as `(X)===(X) is always true for any X`

Comment: @iuliu.net because `[]` is not the same as `x`, but more like `new x()` (it creates a new instance) everytime it is called. If you do `var x = []; x === x` you will get the expected result.

Comment: Yeah well assuming that `X` is variable sure, alright, it's correct (and of course assuming no proxies were applied). But the answer assumes `X` is an expression, in which case my clarification stands.

Comment: Note that I added a comment about assuming `X` is a non-destructive or read-only expression. Neither `[]` nor `{}` are read-only expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` will create a **new** array instance. Two instance are different from each other (you can modify them independently). The same holds for `{}`, it creates a new object instance.

All array instances share the same prototype instance (there is only a single array prototype instance). The prototype of an array prototype is an object.

They just happen to have the same string/JSON representation.

What you are basically doing in your second `console.log` example is: `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf([])))`

The last two lines return false because you are comparing objects and arrays (which cannot be equal)