# transposing an array list in processing

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing

I am trying to write a function in processing.js that takes as an input an array list with 4 lists of class `int[]` each containing 4 elements. This is how I am representing a matrix, with each list in the array list representing a row. Index 0 of the Array list is the top row and index 3 of the array list it the bottom row. I want to write a function to transpose this array list, but I have run into a snag. here is my code so far (note: Z is a 4x4 arraylist filled with zeros):

```
ArrayList<int[]> Transpose(ArrayList<int[]> M){
  ArrayList<int[]> A=Z;
  for (int q=0; q<4; q++){
    int[] atemp={};
    for (int p=0; p<4; p++){
      int[] mtemp=M.get(p);
      int i=mtemp[q];
      append(atemp,i);
    }
    A.add(atemp);
  }
  return A;
}
```

My problem seems to be happen when I try to append `i` to `atemp`. When I print out the `atemp.length` right before it is added to `A`, it prints a length of 0. I am not sure why atemp has remained empty, and I am wondering if anyone can help me understand what is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: I actually need to change the `ArrayList<int[]> A=Z;` line to `ArrayList<int[]> A=new ArrayList<int[]>();` so it returns a 4x4 array list instead of an 8x4, but i still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no JavaScript expert (you tagged this question with Java, that's why I looked) but I think you should create an array like this in JS:

```
int[] atemp = [];
```

With the curly braces you might be creating an object?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is just the syntax of processing. When I tried what you suggested I got a error code that I didn't get before.

Comment: I think I was right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33515070/181336

Answer (score 0):

You've already figured out that you need to allocate `A` as a new `ArrayList` as opposed to simply making another reference to an existing one.

Additionally, if you simply need a 4x4 transformation matrix in Processing.js use the `PMatrix3D` class which already has `transpose()` implemented:

```
PMatrix3D A = new PMatrix3D();
// modify A as a test
A.translate(10, 20, 30);
println("A:");
A.print();
// clone A
PMatrix3D Z = A.get();
Z.transpose();
println("Z:");
Z.print();
```

which should output:

```
A:
 01.0000  00.0000  00.0000  10.0000
 00.0000  01.0000  00.0000  20.0000
 00.0000  00.0000  01.0000  30.0000
 00.0000  00.0000  00.0000  01.0000

Z:
 01.0000  00.0000  00.0000  00.0000
 00.0000  01.0000  00.0000  00.0000
 00.0000  00.0000  01.0000  00.0000
 10.0000  20.0000  30.0000  01.0000
```

(You can use `applyMatrix()` to apply the transformation to the renderer).

Bare in mind ProcessingJS is no longer maintained.