# Add a new object to an existing object. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have read [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object) and others but more complex
For referrence:

```
let newpage = {
  page_no_3: {
    data1: [{index: 1, text: "test1"}],
    data2: [{index: 1, text: "test2"}],
  }
}
```

What I want to happen when I add new object:

```
let newpage = {
  page_no_3: {
    data1: [{index: 1, text: "test2"}, {index: 2, text: "test3"}, ...]
    data2: [{index: 1, text: "test2"}, {index: 2, text: "test4"}, ...]
  }
}
```

NOTE: Sorry it should not be an array but an object.

NOTE2: Sorry again. it should be Array with objects as elements.

PS: When I try to get the data of data1 before inserting, it is giving me an undefined error. I tried it like this:

```
let page_no = 'page_no_3'
if (nextpage.length == 0) {
    ///
} else { // Both undefined
    console.log(nextpage[page_no].data1)
    console.log(nextpage["page_no_3"].data1)
}
```

But if I only `console.log(nextpage[page_no])` I can see the {index: 1, text: "test2"}.

Comment: `data 1` has a space in it. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "add `array1[2]1 in data 1`? Do you want to convert data 1 into an array? Also, you cannot have spaces in keys in your object, unless you enclosed them in quotes.

Comment: Can you please show a real reference, the pseudo-reference is not accurate enough.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want probably this `newpage["page_no_3"].data1 = array1[2]` works for you

Comment: sorry if I added a space in data and 1. no there are no spaces

Comment: @Terry No not an array, but data1 should be able to have multiple objects inside. I will try to edit my question

Comment: Please include some dummy data and show us the expected object you want with your code/logic. See [ask].

Comment: How do you plan to use one specific object from those designed by data1 ?
With an index ? That would make data1 an array.
With a key ? You would need something like 
`data1 : { "first": {index: 1, text: "test2"}, "second" : {index: 2, text: "test3"},... }`

Comment: with an index. so an array.

Comment: Can you please update your question with a complete declaration of the object and how you use it ? The fact that `console.log(nextpage["page_no_3"])` return `{index: 1, text: "test2"}` mean that your structure is like this :
`nextpage = { page_no_3:{index:1, text: "test2"}}` . IE page_no_3 doesn't have the data1 property.

Answer (score 0):

First check that your array exist :

```
if(newpage["page_no_3"].data1 === undefined){
   newpage["page_no_3"].data1 = [];
}
```

Then you can add a new object to data1 :

```
newpage["page_no_3"].data1.push(myAwesomeObject);
```

maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33515070/10707092) can help you to understand the difference between arrays and objects

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. However, I did try `newpage["page_no_3"].data1` and `newpage[page_no].data1` but it is giving me a Cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: is `newpage` defined ? is `newpage["page_no_3"]` defined ?
You need to define everything before using it, newpage and the properties you want to access (here "page_no_3")

Comment: yes. everything is defined before the if else here.