# How to lookup associative array/object value in Ember template using string key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I know that the traditional syntax for looking up array values (by key) in Ember is to use `.[]` syntax, like:

```
{{myArray.[0]}}
```

However, I have an associative array, and despite having a separate model/controller property that lists the keys, I'm unable to perform a lookup - the value is always `undefined`.

As an example, here is a simple controller:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        var ret = [];
        ret['notGreat'] = ['Plain Yogurt', 'Clams'];
        ret['great'] = ['Pizza', 'Chicken'];
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            keys: ['great', 'notGreat'],
            array: ret
        });

    }
});
```

And my template uses:

```
    {{#each key in model.keys}}
      <li>{{key}}</li>
      {{#each subItem in model.array.[key]}}
          <li>Subitem: {{subItem}}</li>
```

Though the `model.array.[key]` always seems to be undefined. Is there a trick to associative array lookups in Ember? I would also be happy writing a controller function like `getFoodsWithKey(key)`, but haven't found any resources indicating that calling a controller *function* (as opposed to a computed property, which to support their caching paradigm, doesn't allow parameters) is possible.

JSFiddle (array notation): http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/786/

JSFiddle (object property notation): http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/787/

Comment: Please note that JS doesn't have "associative arrays", though it does have objects which can have keys to accomplish the same thing. In short, `var ret = []; ret['foo'] = 'bar';` is improper and should not be used. Instead, use `var ret = {}; ret['foo'] = 'bar';`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/874205/84473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Ember 2.0+ you can use the [`each-in` helper](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/) which was announced [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_each-in-helper).

The template would become:

```
<ul>
{{#each-in model.array as |key value|}}
  <li>{{key}}: {{value}}</li>
{{/each-in}}
</ul>
```

The [`get` helper](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_get-helper) can also be used to get a specific value by its key:

```
{{get items 'Item 1'}}
{{get items somePathWithAKey}}
```

[JSBin demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/puragabila/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: That's great, thanks - this works for a situation in which you want to print _all_ the elements (with their keys), which is what I described. But as an addendum, do you know if there's a way to access a `value` given a _specific_ `key`?

Comment: @CraigOtis yes, you can use the `get` helper. Updated my post and demo with examples. Unfortunately I can't find this in the official docs, just the announcement link.