# Does pushing Json/ajax information into an array create an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, for-loop

Having a issue with this twitch app, if you check the console it logs an empty array, but then the array contains objects with the right information. I log typeof on the array and it displays object. I'm so confused I was trying to push the names into an array so I could use them in the for loop that followed.

```
$(document).ready(() => {

  let followerNames = [];

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    asynx: false,
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/SCKADOOSH/follows/channels",
    headers: {
       'Client-ID': 'drj8nyih5rn8z2go1x0fgga6dmudwx'
    },
    success: (data2) => {

        for (var i = 0; i < data2.follows.length; i++) {  //check number of folowers user has
          const usersCurrentFollowers = data2.follows[i]; //check the array and get the channel names of followers
          followerNames.push(usersCurrentFollowers.channel.display_name); //push that channel name into an array of user's followers
        }
    }
  });

  console.log(followerNames);



    for (var j = 0; j < followerNames.length; j++) { //iterate over the array of follower names
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+followerNames[j],
        headers: {
         'Client-ID': 'drj8nyih5rn8z2go1x0fgga6dmudwx'
        },
        success: (data) => {  
            // console.log(data);

            let streamStatus = data.stream; //status of the users stream offline/online
            // console.log(channelUrl);

            if (streamStatus === null) { //check if streaming or not....if not streaming
            const offlineChannelLogo = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/User-offline.svg/1024px-User-offline.svg.png"; //placeholder logo for offline streamer
            $("#status").append("<h3> Offline </h3>") //set status to offline
            $("#logo").append("<img class='streamerLogo' src='" + offlineChannelLogo + "'/>"); //logo to placeholder logo
            $("#streamerName").append("<h3>User Offline</h3>"); //set current stream/game to 'User Offline'

        } else { //if currently online streaming
            const channelLogo = data.stream.channel.logo; //get channel logo
            const streamerName = data.stream.channel.display_name; //get streamer name
      const streamLink = "https://www.twitch.tv/"+streamerName; //get link to streamers schannel
            $("#status").append("<h3><a href=" + streamLink +">" + streamStatus.game + "</a></h3>") //display game currently streaming on channel
            $("#logo").append("<img class='streamerLogo' src='" + channelLogo + "'/>"); //display channel logo
            $("#streamerName").append("<h3>"+ streamerName+"</h3>"); //display streamer name
        }
    }
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: You can't eat a pizza before it is delivered. Ajax is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Arrays *are* objects. Almost everything is. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object).

As for the `console.log()`, you log after you've made the ajax request, not after the result has come, that's why you get an empty array - because there is no data *yet*. You should put the log inside the `success` callback in order to log the data.