# JavaScript, array A length is 0 but A[key] has value

Tags: javascript

Here is the code

```js
var A = [];
A['key1'] = 'apple';
console.log(A.length);
console.log(A['key1']);
```

A.length is 0 in the log.... But I just don't get it, apparently A['key1'] has a value 'apple'. Why A.length is 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are define `A` is array .Array is not `key and value` pair,Object only have `key value pair`

Check the console.log `A` its still empty

```js
 var A = [];
    A['key1'] = 'apple';//its not added because is a array
    console.log(A);    
    console.log(A.length);
```

If you need to add `key value pair` Define `A` as a Object.and find the length using [`Object.keys(A)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjy6uHwiuXTAhXLPI8KHc5vArkQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw) .It will create array of the Object keys

```js
var A = {};
    A['key1'] = 'apple';
    console.log(A);    
    console.log(Object.keys(A).length);
    console.log(A.key1.length)
```

Better see the [Difference between an array and an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object)

Comment: Thanks, man. It's clear for me now. But how can I loop A's sub values if A is an object?

Comment: Just found the method myself, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-plain-javascript-object-with-objects-as-members

Comment: @Ranger22 Apply the loop in sub value using [`Object.keys(A)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirz6SMkeXTAhUTSo8KHXfCC6YQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw) its create the array of keys only .[`Object.values(A)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) its create the array of  values of the Object.Apply the loop from this

Comment: Good .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-plain-javascript-object-with-objects-as-members in this more no of the possible loop function .You could choose any on of this from

Answer (score 1):

You are using javascript associative array which don't have the built-in function like length to get the number of properties in the array. So Instead of using length function you can use the following line to get the number of properties in the array.

```
      Object.keys(A).length
```