# Stringify not working when storing named array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage, stringify

I have named arrays that I want store in local storage.

For example:

```
testla=[];

testla['aaaa']='a';
```

However, when I try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(testla));
```

This outputs:

```
[]
```

And even more weird, when using:

```
testla=[];

testla[10]='a';
```

I get strange results like this:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"a"]
```

According to docs, localstorage can only store strings, therefore stringifying makes sense to me, but apparently it doesn't work, so there must be other way of doing this.

Comment: _"I have named arrays"_ - no you don't, because that's not a thing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify() ignores non-array properties of arrays. But you can use objects: `var testla = {};` .

Comment: I use objects to store other variables but I want to achieve this with named arrays particularly.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are just adding a property call aaa to your object. Same as

```
testla.aaaa = 'foo';
```

You can create an associative array by using an object as so :

```
var myArr = {};
myArr['aaaa'] = 'bar';
```

There is no such thing as a named array, arrays in js can only be indexed using numbers.