# How to remove null values from an object from a database?

Tags: javascript, angular, object

Simple I have an object that looks like this which is returned directly from a stored procedure in my chrome browser. How can I remove the ones that say `null` in `javascript/angular 2`?

[image: Object]

Comment: Can you please, check my answer and share the format of the array you want to filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all you don't have an array according to your provided image**. It's an `object` and everyone thought you have an `array` due to your misguided title. So you can not use `filter` function right away. You can do something like this to filter the `object`.

```js
var object = {
  C1: "123456",
  C2: "1234",
  C3: null,
  C4: null,
  C5: null,
  C6: "4567"
}

var MAP = {
  C1: "Product",
  C2: "Product Description",
  C3: "Date",
  C4: "",
  C5: "",
  C6: "Date"
}

for (var key in object) {
  if (object[key] === null) {
    delete object[key];
  } else {
    object[MAP[key]] = object[key];
    delete object[key];
  }
}

console.log(object);
```

**UPDATE**

I updated your answer to cater extra needs.
Keep in mind that the `MAP` object should have a one to one mapping with `key` and `value`.

Comment: One more question. Lets say I wanted to give these C1, C2 etc a title of Product, Product Description, Date. How can I do that if I have a list of 5 objects exactly like this

Comment: This is awesome Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`null` seems to be the only falsy values, so you could do just

```
arr = arr.filter(Boolean);
```

If it's just an object with keys, you could do

```js
var obj = {c1 : 's', c2 : 's', c3 : null, c4 : null};

Object.entries(obj).forEach( o => (o[1] === null ? delete obj[o[0]] : 0));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Why did you use `Boolean` instead of `el => el`?

Comment: @HermanLauenstein I've never seen this either, but I suppose `Boolean` is there to cast whatever it gets into a `boolean` - truthy/falsy values. Since constructor is a function, you can pass it as an argument to `filter`.

Comment: Indeed, passing in `Boolean` will return the result of using the `Boolean` constructor on the values, and any falsy values, including `null` in this case, is filtered out.

Answer (score 6):

Use array filter:

```
var filtered = arr.filter(el => el !== null);
```

And even simpler (but this will filter other [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) as well):

```
var filtered = arr.filter(el => el);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work  I am using let filtered :any[] = dataObj.Errors[0].LineList.filter(el => el !== null);  It isn't removing those values that are null. Its still the same exact list. Should I do a splice?

Comment: You should note that there is a difference between the  2 methods in some cases. what i want to say is that the 2 lines is not the same (in some other cases). so. you need to take care when using them.

Answer (score 6):

The image that you attach in your question is for an `object` not an `array`

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/874205/6568620) answers to know the difference between them.

---

**To remove all `null` values from an `array`:**

You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

*Ex:*

```js
const arr = [1, "a", null, "name", null, 100];
const newArr = arr.filter( e =>   e !== null);

console.log(newArr); // [1, "a", "name", 100]
```

---

**To remove all properties with a `null`value from an `object`:**

You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ,  [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) methods

*Ex:*

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: "name", c: null, d: 100, e: null};
const newObj = Object.keys(obj)
               .filter(e => obj[e] !== null)
               .reduce( (o, e) => {
                    o[e]  = obj[e]
                    return o;
               }, {});
                      

console.log(newObj); // {"a": 1,"b": "name", "d": 100 }
```

---

**To remove all properties from an `object` inside `array` of `objects`:**

You can combine all of the previous methods in addition to [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

*Ex:*

```js
const arrOfObjects = [
    {a: null, b: "name", c: null, d: 100, e: "name"},
    {f: 1, g: null, h: 23, i: null, j: null},
    {k: null, l: "name", m: null, n: 100, o: "name"}
]

const newArrOfObjects = arrOfObjects
    .map(
        obj => 
        Object.keys(obj).filter(e => obj[e] !== null)
        .reduce((o, e) => {o[e]  = obj[e]; return o;}, {})
    )

console.log(newArrOfObjects)
```