# Get value from select2 multiple then shows alert javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a input with `select2` like below

```
<select class="form-control" name="location" multiple="multiple" id="location"></select>
```

So I want user to input / type the location, and user can typing it multiple times and each location separated by press enter button

I want to make system, that if user have `10` locations needed to input, when location number `7` input have same value with location number `3` user typed before, it shows `alert` to make user aware.

Right now, if user typing location number `7` input input have same value with location number `3` user typed before, the data location number `7` is just disappear.

So I want to get `value` from `location` selected, but I'm confused how to get data that just disappear like the case above. I tried to make `if` condition, if `value` of `location` is not increased, it shows an `alert` javascript, but it's not showing an alert

Here's the code

```
 $('.select2').on('change', function() {
    var test = $("#location").val(); 
    console.log(test) // shows value in array like ["location 1","location 2",..]
    var a = test.length
    if(a != a+1)
    {
        alert("you already input that location");
    }
 })
```

Any clue would be help me, thank you

Comment: What if you made the event listener function take a parameter of `e` and then try to alert `e.target.innerText`

Comment: if you think about it, this if condition will always be true `if(a != a+1)` you rather want to check the arrays values sth like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215358/checking-for-duplicate-strings-in-javascript-array

Comment: Hi @Zak, how to do that ?

Comment: Hi @johnSmith, still have a problem, when I do `console.log(test)`, if location number `7` is same with location number `3`, the location number `7` is not entering an array

Comment: i guess its already built in by select2 that you can not have same input twice? so its working already as you expect?

Comment: `a` will never equal `a+1`

Comment: Note that a `select2` pills picker is just a wrapper over a `<select multiple>`.  You're getting the value from the `select`.  You can't add the same value twice in a `<select multiple>`.   Try without the `select2` wrapper in the first instance and you'll see that `$("select").val()` always picks the values you have chosen, in the order they appear in the `select`.

Comment: HI @johnSmith yes, it is

Comment: hi @freedomn-m I've tried this code like you're suggest `$('.select2').on('change', function(){ var v = $("select").val; console.log(v) })`, but I just have this code in `console.log` `f(t){var e,i,n,a=this[0];return arguments.length?(n=m(t),this.each((function(i){var a;1===this.nodeType&&(null==(a=n?t.call(this,i,x(this).val()):t)?a="":"number"==typeof ...`

Comment: I don't think I would ever suggest `.val` - try `.val()` - and learn to recognise when you've output a function definition into the console so need to and `()`.   And I was just explaining what the code you already have does, not suggesting you change the selector to `select` - that's just easier to type and more general than your specific id.