# How can verify if exist duplicates of an element in an array?

Tags: javascript

I am doing like this, this is my code to know if there are duplicates

```js
const value = 'a'
const value2 = 'c'
const arr = [{
  name: 'a'
}, {
  name: 'b'
}]

const result = arr.filter((d) => d.name === value).length !== 1
console.log(result)
const result2 = arr.filter((d) => d.name === value2).length !== 1
console.log(result2)
```

there is another way to do this properly? with .some(), .includes or other functions, i think my function its hard

***note:*** arr contains objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking for duplicate strings in JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215358/checking-for-duplicate-strings-in-javascript-array)

Comment: @PM77-1 but my array contains objects

Comment: @letters I recommend showing a basic example of your array, that will give users the ability to test out and get a working example based on your actual data.

Comment: some() is what you are looking for `const hasDupe = arr.some(({name}) => name === value )`

Comment: How do you define the "duplicate" for your objects?

Comment: @epascarello wouldn't that return true also when only 1 element fulfils the condition? I think OP needs at least 2

Comment: @GrafiCode yes at least 2

Comment: You'll need to explain "at least 2".  It changes the whole task you're doing from "checking if value exists in arr" to "checking arr for duplicates in general".  And you didn't provide enough supporting code for us to be able to tell.

Comment: Um, not sure where "2" came from when it would be one.... makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const
  value  = 'a'
, value2 = 'c'
, arr    = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }]
, uniqElm = x => (1 === arr.reduce((r,{name}) => r + (name===x)?1:0,0))
  ;

console.log( value,  ', is present and unique ?', uniqElm(value)  )
console.log( value2, ', is present and unique ?', uniqElm(value2) )
```

Comment: no, i need two appears in my array

Comment: @letters  oh, i'm having a little trouble understanding the real question, does updating my answer fit better?

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic could fail with the case I fix below:

```js
const value = 'a'
const value2 = 'c'

const arr = [{
  name: 'a'
}, {
  name: 'b'
},
{
  name: 'a'
}
]

const result = arr.some((d) => d.name === value)
console.log(result)
const result2 = arr.some((d) => d.name === value2)
console.log(result2)
```

Semantically and better in performance I think it is better to use some. It will stop iterating with the first success match found.